# HTML5 LocalStorage reload document

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've got such a problem: I have to add some images to the gallery and after reloading the page they should still be there. I've already managed to accomplish that, elements are added to the array and everything's fine. After reloading the document they are in local storage too. However, having reloaded the document and after trying to add some other pictures the array is being overwritten. 
So instead of: 
`[img1, image, image, ..., imgn]` I get 
`[imgn, image, img2]` again.
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
          var imageList = [];
          $('.addPic').click(function() { 
                 var image = $(this).attr('data-image'); //this variable contains particular image ID
                 imageList.push(image);
                 localStorage.setItem("imageList", JSON.stringify(imageList)); 
          });
        });

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong guys? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first GET the items from localstorage to merge them with the new items you want to save before actually saving them back to localstorage again. You also do not need the imageList variable in this example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var LIST_ID = 'imageList';

    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.addPic').click(function() { 
              var image = $(this).attr('data-image'),
                  items= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LIST_ID)) || []; 

              items.push(image);
              localStorage.setItem(LIST_ID, JSON.stringify(items)); 
          });
     });

</script>
```

Comment: I've just explored something. This works only when there are already some elements in the list. Otherwise I get an error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'items.push')

Comment: That is because the items var is not an array at that point. See my edit for a fix.

Answer (score 3):

In the code you show, you never use the storage you declared. As a consequence, you only store what is currently present in `imageList` array.

You should declare imageList by reading the local storage :

```
var imageList = localStorage.getItem("imageList");
```